# javascript for loop to print multiple lines within html div

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen a bunch of examples that are **close**, but none that are right on.

I'm building a program that is an HTA form where people can enter multiple lines of similar data (ex. mailing addresses). The number of lines that the user will enter is determined by an `input` box that receives a number:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Entry Application</title>
    <hta:application id = "ExampleHTA" singleInstance = "yes" icon = "macexp.ico" border = "thin" minimizeButton = "no" maximizeButton = "no" scroll = "yes" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function numOfLines(choice)
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < choice; ++i)
        {
          document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML = "<br />Name: <input type='text' id='Name' size=50 maxlength=50 /> Address: <input type='text' id='Address' size=50 maxlength=50 /> City: <input type='text' id='City' size=15 maxlength=15 /> State: <input type='text id='State' size=2 maxlength=2 /> Zip Code: <input type='text' id='Zip' size=5 maxlength=5 />";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Number of Address Lines: <input type="text" id="AddyLines" size=2 maxlength=2 onChange="numOfLines(this.value);">
      <div id="addy_lines"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r9KEH/

When the user enters a number in the `AddyLines` `input` box, the same number of lines should appear in the `div id="addy_lines"` section.

Example: The user enters **5**, then five `input` lines should be created. Currently, only one address `input` line gets created within the `div` tags.

Comment: Like Jurik mentioned, you're creating duplicate IDs. Use classes or increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML = "<br />Name: <input type='text' id='Name' size=50 maxlength=50 /> Address: <input type='text' id='Address' size=50 maxlength=50 /> City: <input type='text' id='City' size=15 maxlength=15 /> State: <input type='text id='State' size=2 maxlength=2 /> Zip Code: <input type='text' id='Zip' size=5 maxlength=5 />";
```

but you need to add the string, not overwrite the innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML+= '<br/>' +
     'Name: <input type="text" id="Name" size="50" maxlength="50" /> ' +
     'Address: <input type="text" id="Address" size="50" maxlength="50" /> ' +
     'City: <input type="text" id="City" size="15" maxlength="15" /> ' +
     'State: <input type="text" id="State" size="2" maxlength="2" /> ' +
     'Zip Code: <input type="text" id="Zip" size="5" maxlength="5" />';
```

**But overall it is a bad solution, because now you have several input fields with same `id` but id should be unique.**

So this might be much better:

```
document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML+= '<br />' +
    'Name: <input type="text" id="Name-' + i + '" size="50" maxlength="50" /> ' +
    'Address: <input type="text" id="Address-' + i + '" size="50" maxlength="50" /> ' +
    'City: <input type="text" id="City-' + i + '" size="15" maxlength="15" /> ' +
    'State: <input type="text" id="State-' + i + '" size="2" maxlength="2" /> ' +
    'Zip Code: <input type="text" id="Zip-' + i + '" size="5" maxlength="5" />';
```

Further I would give all elements a name and use classes instead of id to target them better with jQuery. But that is up to you.

Comment: This solution worked: `document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML+=...`. I will look into giving the elements their own name. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML = "<br />Name: <input type='text' id='Name' size=50 maxlength=50 /> Address: <input type='text' id='Address' size=50 maxlength=50 /> City: <input type='text' id='City' size=15 maxlength=15 /> State: <input type='text id='State' size=2 maxlength=2 /> Zip Code: <input type='text' id='Zip' size=5 maxlength=5 />";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML = document.getElementById("addy_lines").innerHTML + "<br />Name: <input type='text' id='Name' size=50 maxlength=50 /> Address: <input type='text' id='Address' size=50 maxlength=50 /> City: <input type='text' id='City' size=15 maxlength=15 /> State: <input type='text id='State' size=2 maxlength=2 /> Zip Code: <input type='text' id='Zip' size=5 maxlength=5 />";
```

You should append the changes and not replace them.

Comment: Not that good because now he has same `id`s and they should be unique.